# django permission issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi Everyone I m dealing with some serious issue in django-admin.I have created models with app_label in class Meta

But when i tried to create a group for alloting specific permissions I cant find them in my selection list.But if i remove app_label from my model I can see the model in my permission list.But I cant go without app_label, so i need to fix this asap.When i run a select query on db table 'django_content_type' i can see my app_label but they dont have any entry in auth_permission table.

Is this a bug in django or i m doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed used the meaning of app label